# Flutter: The element type 'Map<dynamic, String>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Player'

Tags: flutter

`Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async { ... await DatabaseService(uid: user!.uid).updateUserData(UserData( player:[{name:'name',rol:'rol'}], }`

I cant inizialite player, error: The element type 'Map<dynamic, String>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Player'.

`class UserData { final List<Player> player; UserData({required this.player}) }`

`class Player{final String name;final String rol; Player({required this.name, required this.rol});}`

Comment: Thumbs up, and leave a comment if you need another help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says that the method `updateUserData()` is receiving the `Player` class instead of a `map()`.

In this case, you can create a method in `UserData` class, called UserData.toJson().

Supposing your Json should be like this:

```
{
  "player": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "rol": "rol"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "rol": "rol"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "rol": "rol"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your **UserData** and **Player** classes should be like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

UserData userDataFromJson(String str) => UserData.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userDataToJson(UserData data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserData {
    UserData({
        this.player,
    });

    List<Player> player;

    factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
        player: List<Player>.from(json["player"].map((x) => Player.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "player": List<dynamic>.from(player.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Player {
    Player({
        this.name,
        this.rol,
    });

    String name;
    String rol;

    factory Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Player(
        name: json["name"],
        rol: json["rol"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "rol": rol,
    };
}
```

Then in your function call:

```
...updateUserData(UserData.toJson());
```

This is a tool that can help you with your model classes in this case https://app.quicktype.io/